# Operator valued functions

Tags: operators

For some parts of physics it is useful to define an operator valued function

Take for example

```
R[K_] := Sum[K[[j]] D[#, K[[j]]], {j, 1, 4}]
```

It is supposed to be an operator and I placed a # where the function should be, to which the operator will be applied to i.e.

```
R[K]&@F[K[[1]],...]
```

It is important however, that R remains a function of the parameters only. That means that the result of R[K] is still an operator. 
The way, I created the operator does not work, do you now, how to do it?

Do you know in particular, how one could write the above operator as a scalar product where one vector consists of

```
K={a,b,c,d}
```

and the other is a Vectoroperator

DEL={$\partial_t$,$\partial_x$,$\partial_y$,$\partial_z$}

such that one can take e.g.

```
((K.DEL)+1) &@ f
```

I am happy about every hint.